# Filter custom struct array through function in Swift

Tags: swift

So, I have a struct

```swift
struct myCoolStruct {
    var id: Int
    var enabled: Bool

    let array = [
        myCoolStruct(id: 1, enabled: true)
        myCoolStruct(id: 2, enabled: true)
        myCoolStruct(id: 3, enabled: false)
    ]
}
```

I want to write a function where I can make a new struct array of only the ones that are enabled. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would solve this by writing a function like this:

```swift
func onlyEnabled() -> Array<myCoolStruct> {
    var newArray: Array<myCoolStruct>
    newArray = myCoolStruct().array.filter(\.enabled)
    return newArray
}
```

You can also write one that can sit inside your myCoolStruct like this:

```swift
func onlyEnabled() -> Array<myCoolStruct> {
    let newArray = array.filter(\.enabled)
    return newArray
}
```

Comment: No problem! If it solved your problem I would be very grateful if you marked it as accepted :)

Comment: `== true` is redundant. Go with `array.filter(\.enabled)`. It doesn't warrant a function.

Comment: @Jessy, good point. I'll update the answer. also edit: I hope it wasn't you who downvoted just for that..